# Error NoReverseMatch en django

Tags: django, django-forms

Estoy recibiendo el siguiente error en mi pagina hecha con django.

> Reverse for 'suscrito' with keyword arguments '{'nombre': u'ImHarvol'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['edoras/newsletter/suscrito$']

La pagina consiste en un formulario, que después de completarlo, te tiene que redirigir a la view *suscrito*.

**urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^newsletter$', views.newsletter, name='newsletter'),
    url(r'^newsletter/suscrito$', views.suscrito, name='suscrito'),
]
```

**views.py**:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render

### Create your views here.

from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect
from .forms import SuscripcionForm
from .models import Suscripcion
from .modulos import *

def index(request):
#   return render(request, 'edoras/index.html', {})
    return redirect(newsletter)

def newsletter(request):
#   return render(request, 'edoras/newsletter.html', {})
    x_forwarded_for = request.META.get('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip = x_forwarded_for.split(',')[0]
    else:
        ip = request.META.get('REMOTE_ADDR')

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SuscripcionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            suscripcion = form.save(commit=False)
            suscripcion.ip = ip
            fsuscripciones = open("/home/imharvol/web/edoras/botsuscripciones/twitters.txt", "a")
            fsuscripciones.write('\n@'+suscripcion.nombre_twitter)
            fsuscripciones.close
            suscripcion.save()
            sendmessage(suscripcion.nombre_twitter)
            return redirect('suscrito', nombre=suscripcion.nombre_twitter)
    else:
        form = SuscripcionForm()

    return render(request, 'edoras/newsletter.html', {'form': form})

def suscrito(request, nombre):
    return render(request, 'edoras/suscrito.html', {'nombre': nombre})
```

Supongo que el error se debe a esta linea `return redirect('suscrito', nombre=suscripcion.nombre_twitter)`. Ahí estoy intentando mandar el nombre que hayan puesto en el form, a la view suscrito, para luego imprimir su nombre.

Answer (score 2):

Es que estás pasando un argumento `nombre` que no está configurado. Solo tienes que eliminarlo de la función `redirect`.

Pero si lo que quieres es usar el argumento para tu plantilla, tendrías que cambiar tu `url`  a algo como esto:

```
url(r'^newsletter/suscrito/(?P<nombre>\w+)$', views.suscrito, name='suscrito'),
```

No lo he verificado, pero la expresión del grupo `nombre` debe asegurar que el argumento está bien formado. En este ejemplo, acepta *cualquier* palabra.

Comment: ¿No seria posible pasar el parámetro "nombre" sin tener que cambiar la URL? Lo que quiero es evitar que la url cambie

Comment: Pues pasa el nombre con GET. Así no cambia.